# Is it possible to change default landing tab to my app page?[facebook api]

Tags: facebook-apps

I'm doing facebook app, it create a new tab(other for those who likes this page and who don't ) here is it :
afternoon-planet-6257.herokuapp.com
but it's only scaffold.

Now I want to change this new tab to default landing tab and i didn't find anything how to to do this and i don't even know if it's possible?
ok now it's seperate question:)

Oh i get this question doesn't meet stackoverflow standtards so i wrote this and now it's longer so i think now i can post it: >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Upper right corner of the page, click [Edit Page]
2. Left column, click *Manage Permissions* link
3. In the Default Landing Tab drop down choose your app
4. At the bottom of the page click [Save Changes]

Comment: ok but i know how to user can set default landing page,it's quiet easy. hm i writing app and in this app i want add checklist if it is checked app is set to default landing page.

Comment: There is no programmatic way to set default tabs for a page.  It is a user interaction only from an admin of the page. If non-admins could do it, wouldn't that be a security issue?

Comment: But app is not non-admin, user can give apps permissions and there are dialogs who ask user if app can do something.Anyway thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The new Timeline page format does not allow default landing tabs anymore.

While the answer above is correct for now, it will not be in 3 weeks; the deadline for timeline migrations is March 30th 2012.

Comment: timeline is going to be default tab for anyone? and there is no way to change to other tab? it's just stupid or i'm wrong?

Comment: Correct, timeline will be the default page and the user will have to click on a tab (or be directly linked to it) in order to see it.